# how to send reponse when timeout in node.js http module

Tags: node.js, http, sockets, timeout

On nodejs.org [socket.setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback), it says

> When an idle timeout is triggered the socket will receive a 'timeout' event but the connection will not be severed.

But when I test code like this:

```
var http = require('http');

server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.socket.setTimeout(500);
    request.socket.on('timeout', function () {
        response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('hello world');
        console.log('timeout');
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

The socket is closed immediately after timeout, and no data is replied to the browser.  Which is quite different from the document. Is this a bug or is there any tricks dealing socket under http module?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is indeed correct, however it looks like the `http` module adds a 'timeout' listener which calls `socket.destroy()`. So what you need to do is get rid of that listener by  calling `request.socket.removeAllListeners('timeout')`.
So your code should look like:

```
var http = require('http');

server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    request.socket.setTimeout(500);
    request.socket.removeAllListeners('timeout'); 
    request.socket.on('timeout', function () {
        response.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        response.end('hello world');
        console.log('timeout');
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: This one creates a `timeout` on each request.
It would be better if one common `timeout` could listen, and write the response on the socket.