# Why does a NodeJS http server close socket on timeout without response?

Tags: node.js, express, httpserver, nginx-reverse-proxy

Given a NodeJS http server with a timeout of 10s:

```
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.timeout = 10 * 1000;
```

On timeout, Postman shows this without any response code:

```
Error: socket hang up
Warning: This request did not get sent completely and might not have all the required system headers
```

If the NodeJS server is behind an nginx reverse proxy, nginx returns a 502 response (`upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream`). But here it is just NodeJS/express running on localhost. Still one would expect a proper http response.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14123559/1870795), this is expected behavior, the socket is simply destroyed.

In an architecture with an nginx reverse proxy, is it usual that the server just destroys the socket without sending a timeout response to the proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the [socket timeout when you're setting the http server timeout](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout). The socket timeout prevents abuse from clients that might want to hang on to your connection to DOS you. It has other benefits like ensuring a certain level of service (though these are often more important when you're a client).

The reason it uses a socket timeout instead of sending a `408` status code (Request Timeout) is because the status code might have already been sent for a successful message.

If you want to implement a response timeout on your backend and handle it gracefully, you can timeout the response yourself. Note, you should likely respond with a `408` instead. `502` is for gateways like http proxies (nginx) to indicate that a downstream connection failed.

Here's a simple strawman implementation of handling that.

```
const httpServer = require('http').createServer((req, res) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.statusMessage = "Ok";
        res.end("Done"); // I'm never called because the timeout will be called instead;
    }, 10000)
});

httpServer.on('request', (req, res) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        res.statusCode = 408;
        res.statusMessage = 'Request Timeout';
        res.end();
    }, 1000)
});

httpServer.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate "the status code might have already been sent for a successful message."? In my understanding, if a response had already been sent, the socket wouldn't time out.

Comment: A client might make a request, then never attempt to read the response, thus holding onto the connection. The response sends the status code first. (see these [MSDN HTTP docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) for a good overview). So you can't close the socket and change the status that was already sent over the wire. In HTTP 1.x, it's status first, then headers, then body.

Comment: There is a good wikipedia article on different DDOS attacks. One of which is a [slow read attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Slow_Read_attack), among other similar attacks that are mitigated, to an extent, by timing out the underlying socket, but wouldn't be possible to defend at the HTTP layer itself.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the callback of `setTimeout` is only called on request timeout, not on keepalive timeout. The socket is destroyed in both cases, but only in the first case is the `408` in your code example being sent. So this is unrelated to Slowloris attacks, and a response cannot have been sent already, or am I wrong?

Comment: Correct, the setTimeout is just there to timeout the request, but it doesn't handle the socket timeout itself. You can handle that if you want by grabbing the socket for the request and adding your own handler for the `on:timeout` event, but you should still be sure to close the socket.

You're right that if the socket timeout is less than either of those, you'll just get the same old socket timeout, so socket timeout should be greater than your request timeout. Socket timeout will then only happen when something wonky happened.